# Extending the upper bound from sum to summands

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Assume I have an upper bound on $u$, $\parallel u\parallel \le \epsilon$. Also, consider that I can write $u=cz-v$. What can I say about the upper bounds on $z$ and $v$ individually based on $\epsilon$? $c$ is a constant.

Comment: I'm assuming $u$, $v$, and $z$ are vectors? The reverse triangle inequality gives you $\epsilon \geq ||u|| \geq ||cz||-||v||=|c|||z||-||v||$. You cannot, in general, get any sort of bound on $||z||$ and $||v||$ though. Consider on the real line $u=\epsilon$, $z=x+\epsilon$, and $v=-x$. Then $|z-v|=|x+\epsilon-x|=|\epsilon|$, but $|z|$ and $|v|$ can be made arbitrarily large by changing $x$.

Comment: @kccu thanks! I think you need to change $v=x$.

Comment: @kccu I believe if I can bound $v$ then it is easy to bound $z$, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right about $v=x$. I forgot $v$ was being subtracted. And yes to your second comment as well. If you know, say, $||v||\leq a$, then $cz=v+u$ so $||cz|| \leq ||v||+||u|| \leq a+\epsilon$ by the triangle inequality.